# How to upload photo on facebook wall?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

hi friends i'm trying in this way to post photos on facebook wall

here my control code:

public class test
        {

```
        public FacebookMediaObject mediaObject { get; set; }
    }

public ActionResult Profile(FacebookOAuthResult facebookoAuthResult)
{
    DisplayAppropriatemessage(facebookoAuthResult);

    // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}

private void DisplayAppropriatemessage(FacebookOAuthResult facebookoAuthResult)
{
    if (facebookoAuthResult != null)
    {
        if (facebookoAuthResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(path)
            }
            .SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path));

            var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookoAuthResult.AccessToken);

            fb.PostAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "source", mediaObject } });
        }
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and here my profile.cshtml code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Profile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

while i'm run this code and when i click post button it give following error

Server Error in '/' Application.
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

i'm trying so many ways  but everytime i'm fail

Comment: Does your controller have any constructors defined?

Comment: yes those are following [httppost] and [ValidateInput(false)]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

Comment: please show us the stack trace, will help in pinpointing whereabouts youre trying to call a parameterless constructor

Comment: @suva Those are not constructors, those are attributes.  A constructor would be a function which has a name that is the same as the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

somewhere you are trying to access a constructor and pass in no parameters, all of those constructors you have shown us require a certain parameter, though i can't see anywhere in your code where you do this, so the problem might lie within another part of the application,

Please debug and step through, find the exact line it breaks on and check that you definately pass along a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: Things like `FacebookMediaObject {` would require a parameterless constructor, however, if that were the problem, then he shouldn't be able to even compile it.  Thus, I believe that the offending code is not shown, and is actually either in a cshtml or is a problem with something the framework is calling, such as the Controller not having a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

One guess is you've defined a constructor for your controller that takes a parameter.

Whenever a class has no constructors, then by default there exists a hidden parameterless(has no parameters) constructor.

Whenever you create a constructor that takes a parameter, then you no longer get that automatic default constructor.  MVC will expect that your controller have a parameterless constructor.